# Wrap every two items in a DIV but single-wrap an item if a certain condition is "true"

Tags: php, foreach

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to wrap two items in a DIV and at the same time single wrap an item if a certain condition is "true".

```
<div class='row'>
    <?php 

      $projects = $page->children()->listed();
      $i = 0

      foreach($projects as $project) {
        echo "<article class='project'></article>";
      }

      $i++

      if($project->isFullWidth() == "true") {
        $i++;
      }

      if($i%2 == 0 && $i != count($projects)) {
        echo "</div><div class='row'>"
      }
    ?>
</div>
```

There are two `<article class='project'>`-items next to each other in one `<div class='row'>` if a `project` has the condition `"isFullWidth"`, there should only be one `project` in a `<div class='row'>`.

Expected result:

```
<div class='row'>
    <article class='project'></article>
    <article class='project'></article>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <article class='project isFullWidth'></article>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <article class='project'></article>
    <article class='project'></article>
</div>
```

Actual result:

```
<div class='row'>
    <article class='project'></article>
    <article class='project'></article>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <article class='project isFullWidth'></article>
    <article class='project'></article>
    <article class='project'></article>
</div>
<div class='row'></div>
<div class='row'></div>
```

Comment: If you removed so many of the `<?php` start and the tags your code would be much more readable.

Comment: Thanks, I reformatted it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tries to keep track of the number of items output, each time a new row is output it resets the counter so that the next one can be tracked.  It also will produce a new row if you have (for example) 1 normal followed by 1 full width will be split.

```
$i = 0;
echo "<div>";
foreach($projects as $project) {
    // Start new row for full width (unless just started one)
    if($project->isFullWidth() == "true" && $i != 0) {
        echo "</div>".PHP_EOL."<div class='row'>";
    }
    echo "<article class='project".($project->isFullWidth()? "isFullWidth":"")."'></article>";
    $i++;
    // End row if needed and reset column count
    if($project->isFullWidth() == "true" || ($i == 2 && $i != count($projects))) {
        echo "</div>".PHP_EOL."<div class='row'>";
        $i = 0;
    }
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the correction of the code, sir! It works as intended! Sometimes there's an empty/blank <div class='row'></div> at the end of all the <div class='row'>s. But I'll just remove/delete them via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<div class='row'>
    <?php $projects = $page->children()->listed(); ?>

    <?php $i = 0 ?>

    <?php foreach($projects as $key => $project): ?>
        <article class='project'></article>

        <?php $i++ ?>

          <?php if($project->isFullWidth() === "true"): ?>
            <?php $i = 2; ?>
          <?php endif ?>

          <?php if($i === 2): ?>
            <?php echo "</div><div class='row'>" ?>
            <?php $i = 0 ?>
          <?php endif ?>

    <?php endforeach ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your input! Unfortunately this only works, if the isFullWidth() is true for the last project of the x-amount projects. : / Thank you though!